# Android drawer layout not showing

Tags: java, android

I am new to android development. I am trying to implement a drawer layout  there isn't error in the build but the drawer hamburger icon doesn't show.
here is my xml layout

```
 <LinearLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        tools:context=".MainActivity">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            android:minHeight="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
            />

        <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
            android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/drawer"
                android:text="@string/hello_world"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            <ListView android:layout_width="240dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_gravity="start"
                />

        </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
package com.example.arslan.tutsplus02;

import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.View;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
    private ActionBarDrawerToggle mActionBarDrawerToggle;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

        mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        mActionBarDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this,mDrawerLayout,R.string.drawer_opened,R.string.drawer_closed)
        {
            @Override
            public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                if (getSupportActionBar()!= null ) {
                    getSupportActionBar().setTitle(R.string.drawer_opened);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onDrawerClosed(View drawerView) {
                super.onDrawerClosed(drawerView);
                if (getSupportActionBar()!= null ) {
                    getSupportActionBar().setTitle(R.string.drawer_closed);
                }
            }
        };
        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mActionBarDrawerToggle);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
        mActionBarDrawerToggle.syncState();

    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        mActionBarDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        if (mActionBarDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item))
        {
            return true;
        }

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try by adding Toolbar to your ActionBarDrawerToggle.

```
mActionBarDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this,mDrawerLayout,toolbar,R.string.drawer_opened,R.string.drawer_closed)
    {
        @Override
        public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
            if (getSupportActionBar()!= null ) {
                getSupportActionBar().setTitle(R.string.drawer_opened);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onDrawerClosed(View drawerView) {
            super.onDrawerClosed(drawerView);
            if (getSupportActionBar()!= null ) {
                getSupportActionBar().setTitle(R.string.drawer_closed);
            }
        }
    };
    mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mActionBarDrawerToggle);
```

Comment: thanks it works .but how come i have add the   toolbar to the  ActionBarDrawerToggle if its not the part of the drawer layout in the xml

Comment: **This class provides a handy way to tie together the functionality of DrawerLayout and the framework ActionBar to implement the recommended design for navigation drawers.** check for further reference [link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/app/ActionBarDrawerToggle.html)

Answer (score 0):

try changing your xml file to

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/main_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        android:minHeight="?android:attr/actionBarSize" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/hello_world" />
</LinearLayout>

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/drawerList"
    android:layout_width="240dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Hope it helps